# How to trigger cmake reconfiguration when tracking git commits in a CLion remote toolchain

Tags: git, build, cmake, clion, git-commit

### Background

I have a C++ project that uses CMake. I wish to encode the current git commit (and "-dirty" flag) into the application in a way that is automatically updated whenever the git commit changes, for example after a successful `git commit` or `git checkout`.

I understand I can do this by having CMake depend on the `.git/index` file, giving this:

```
find_package(Git QUIET REQUIRED)

execute_process(
    COMMAND "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" describe --match=NeVeRmAtCh --always --abbrev=8 --dirty
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    RESULT_VARIABLE res
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT
    ERROR_QUIET
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

set_property(GLOBAL APPEND
    PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git/index")

target_compile_definitions(mylib PUBLIC GIT_COMMIT=\"${GIT_COMMIT}\")
```

Then the target program (C++) can just use the `GIT_COMMIT` preprocessor symbol.

So my requirements are:

- The application will contain the git commit (and `-dirty` suffix if uncommitted changes are present) of the source it was built from,
- The git commit compiled into the application will be updated if the git commit or the dirty flag state changes,
- There should be no recompilation or relinking of the application if the git commit has not changed.

This technique meets these requirements for local builds.

### The Complication

The spanner in the works is that I'm using CLion to remotely compile the application (key issue) on a Raspberry Pi (that specific detail isn't important). Because of how CLion works, the `.git` directory (and therefore `.git/index`) is not copied over to the remote system. Therefore `.git/index` is simply not present when compiling the code on the RPi. This technique therefore fails as the required information is simply not available to the build system on the RPi.

### Question

So I had the idea to somehow automatically create a new file, in the source directory (so that CLion will sync it to the RPi), that is based on `.git/index`, or perhaps just the output of `git describe`, on the host that CLion is running on. I would need this file to be updated whenever the git commit changes. The contents can be used to populate `GIT_COMMIT`. If this file is appended to `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` then it will trigger a reconfiguration when the timestamp on the file changes, regardless of the contents. Instead I'd want the reconfigure to only happen if the *contents* of the file changes, since it will most likely be automatically updated by a generated makefile each time the makefile runs, but without changing the actual commit.

What is the right way to so solve this problem?

At this point I'm wondering if I'm overcomplicating things, so I'd appreciate any comments that might suggest an alternative approach, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you're extracting source for deployment into a non-Git tree, use `git archive` and the `export-subst` and `export-ignore` attributes to customize the contents for deployment. You can for instance run `git log`'s formatter over marked sections of selected files, subbing in the extracted commit id and message and author and what not.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting a way to get the info out of git? I think I can already do that with `git describe`. The problem is that I have no control over the way CLion distributes source code to the remote toolchain. Because CLion knows about git, it also knows not to copy the `.git` directory to the remote, so I still need to find a way to create a file that won't trigger a cmake reconfiguration if it's touched, only if the content changes. Sorry if I've misunderstood you.

Comment: The right way to solve this problem is to fix your tool that refuses to use Git properly.  `git archive` is specifically built for constructing a marked-up source directory for deployment.  Failing that, make a script that builds your marked-up file and then invokes your build.

Comment: Ok, I understand - thank you. Unfortunately I have no way to fix CLion. I'll look at using a script, I'm just not sure how to invoke it on the local side before CLion syncs with the remote system - I may have to run it manually. But that's a CLion issue.